# Paypal - how to restrict receiving payments only from debit and credit cards with indian address

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to use a Paypal "Pay Now" button on my website here: www.karmayog.in
When I click the "pay now" button on the right side, it takes me to a paypal page where there are options to enter details about the debit or credit card.

Is there a way on this page, by which I can only allow users who have an address in India to make a payment here. The website where this "Pay Now" button has been setup has certain legal restriction due to which it can accept payments only from Indian debit and credit cards. Hence, in the country drop-down field I would like to give only India as an option.

Is this possible?

Will greatly appreciate any inputs that can be provided!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since user fills the card information on PayPal's payment page, you can not check if the details are of India or outside. However you should be able to achieve this by asking PayPal to do this check (if you have customization allowed in your agreement.) 
One approach would be to ask the user's country before redirecting to paypal payment page. But there is a chance that user will select India on your page and United States on PayPal's page.